# How to stop an entire cloud service using azure management api?

Tags: azure

I assume most of the things i can do on azure portal can also be done programatically. And i see on the dashboard page of my cloud service, there is a button called "Stop", so is it possible to simulate the behavior of that by writing code?

I know the restful management API and i tried to look for the right thing. but i see only the api for role instance reboot and re-image. There seems no equivalent API for stopping the entire service, or am i missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't even see such a button! And if it's really true the billing doesn't stop it's not very useful.

Comment: @DylanNicholson, right it's not very useful, i was doing some negative test on our service then so i needed to temporarily stop it.

Comment: Actually I found the button and I observed the same thing - when you use the UI all the VMs are stopped and deallocated, but when you use the PowerShell command the VMs are only stopped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do take a look at [`Update Deployment Status`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460808.aspx) REST Operation. In order to stop the deployment, you would need to set `Status` element's value as `Suspended` in the request payload.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UpdateDeploymentStatus xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
  <Status>Suspended</Status>
</UpdateDeploymentStatus>
```

**Update:**

One thing I should have mentioned earlier - when you stop your service, your billing does not stop (at least as of today with cloud services). You continue to incur charges. Thought I should mention that as well.